# Book about seeing another world when the lightning strikes

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for a novel, I read it in the 80s. A man is struck by lightning, he doesn't die, but catches a glimpse of another world, like another dimension, and gets obsessed with  that world. That's the only thing that I remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  So you don't recall if he saw the world again, or ever visited it?  Do you remember anything about the cover of the book

Comment: Set in the 1980s; https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/60880792

Answer (score 1):

Promoting a comment from Valorum:

*[Another Dimension of Us](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/60880792)* by Mike Albo was released in 2023, but is set in the 1980s.

[image: Front cover of Another Dimension of Us]

> In 1986, Tommy Gaye is in love with his best friend, budding teen poet Renaldo Calabasas. But at the height of the AIDS crisis and amidst the homophobia running rampant across America, Tommy can never share his feelings. Then, one terrible night, Renaldo is struck by lightning. And he emerges from the storm a very different boy.
>
> In 2044, Heron High student Pris Devrees jolts awake after having a strange nightmare about a boy named Tommy and a house in the neighborhood the locals affectionally call The Murder House. When she ventures to the house to better understand her vivid dreams, she happens upon an old self-help book that she soon realizes is a guide to trans-dimensional travel.
>
> As bodies and minds merge across the astral plane, Pris, Tommy, and their friends race to save Renaldo from a dangerous demon, while uncovering potent realities about love, sexuality, and friendship.

Comment: Is his name really Tommy Gaye? Talk about 'on-the-nose'. Sheesh.

Comment: And their friend is called Prissy. I swear.

Comment: @Valorum - It says she is called Pris, not Prissy. But I do feel sorry for the poor guy whose family name is "Squashes."